# How to retrieve data from the first row from database in php code

Tags: php, html, sql

I wrote this code to retrieve some data from data base But the code do not display the first value in the table which is started from second row.
How I can make this code retrieve the data from first row.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
$q = " SELECT * FROM student_record WHERE id =201102887;";
$result = mysqli_query($con , $q ) ;
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:500\">";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>courses</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `But the code do not display the first value in the table which is started from second row.`? unable to understand

Comment: start retrieving from second row missing the first row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

to

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

**Updated Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
$q = " SELECT * FROM student_record WHERE id =201102887;";
$result = mysqli_query($con , $q ) ;
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:500\">";
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>courses</th>";
          echo "</tr>";
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
             echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
          }
    echo "</table>";
}   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling mysqli_fetch_array two times second call is going to the second row. Try like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
  $q = " SELECT * FROM student_record WHERE id =201102887;";
  $result = mysqli_query($con , $q ) ;
  $rows = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }

  if(count($rows) > 0) {
      echo "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:500\">";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th>courses</th>";
      echo "</tr>";
      foreach($rows as $row)
      {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $row["grade"]. "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
  }   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why? anything comment

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know when you call this twice,

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

then first row will skip when you call it again in loop, what point you create `if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` ? if you just want check query return you can just use `if($result) {`